# Keyboard shortcut for clone (copy+paste operation)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, listview, copy-paste

We are developing a scientific software which performs a list of measurements called batch. Usually, some group of measurements are similar. So to make it easier for the user to create its batch, we have a feature called clone.

The clone operation make a copy/paste of the selection. The selection is duplicated at the end of the batch.
This operation is accessible through a contextual menu. Contextual menu:

- Clone
- Remove (<kbd>del</kbd>)
- Move up (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>)
- Move down (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>)

We need to set keyboard shortcuts on these operations but we can't find a "standard" keyboard shortcut for this clone. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Illustrator and Balsamiq (i know, they are not scientific tools) the clone action is Ctrl+D (on Win, on Mac it's Cmd+D). While in Illustrator it's actually "repeat transformation". But you can use it for sort of "cloning".

D can stand for "duplicate". So probably instead of labeling the action "clone", you could label it "duplicate" and put Ctrl+D as shortcut on it.

Comment: In the Adobe suite of software Ctrl-J is used to duplicate. Crtl-D is to Deselect. But actually i agree Ctrl-D to duplicate is a more natural response.

Comment: @OpenTage In Illustrator you can i.e. copy-past a path with Alt+Mousedrag (Win). If you press Ctrl+D afterwards (Win), you'll get the path again with the same position offset like the first pasted one. Try it ;-) (Also works for other transformation methods like rotate, scale...)

Comment: After a google search, ctrl+d for duplicate is quite common (Jetbrains resharper, notepad++ ...)
Thanks